# Math - function to return index adding previously skipped indexes

Tags: c++

I was trying to find a way to skip some indexes and add the number of skipped indexes to the index.

for example,

I want to skip all the index divisible by 4, and add those skipped indexes as well.

i.e, if **index = 4**, `4 mod 4 == 0`, so *index becomes 5*.

if **index = 8**, `8 mod 4 == 0`, but *index becomes 10*, because we already had to skip 4.

likewise, if **index = 16**, `16 mod 4 == 0`, but *index becomes 21*. Because 16 + 4 = 20, which again is a multiple of 4, so we skip that and goes to next index, 21.

okay, let me try to explain it through a code snippet i was trying it on.

```
int fn(int i) {
    if (i <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
        return fn(i / 4) + (i / 4);
    } else {
        return i / 4;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int bl = fn(i);
    cout << "block:" << i << endl << "Translated:" << bl << endl;
}
```

But as you can see its not working properly. Any ideas?

Comment: _"But as you can see its not working properly."_ - you'd need to show some actual output for anyone to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I'm assuming `fn` is supposed to return the offset to the normal index. If this is true, **your code is actually correct** - you're just printing the "translated" value wrong. `bl` will contain the offset; this has to be added to `i` in order to get the actual index.</s>

```c
std::cout << "block:" << i << std::endl << "Translated:" << i + bl << std::endl;
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/MetallicOutlyingConditionals)

This function is better solved through logic than recursion. We're skipping every third index; ergo, we need only add 1 to the index after every 3 steps.

```c
#include <iostream>

int fn(int i) {
  if (i <= 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  int offset = (i-1)/3;
  return offset;
}

int main() {

  for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
    int bl = fn(i);
    std::cout << "block:" << i << std::endl << "Translated:" << i + bl << std::endl;
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/MetallicOutlyingConditionals)

Comment: we are very close, but index 13 returns 16! Which should be 17.

Comment: According to your logic, index 13 should return 16. 12/4=3, so 12 returns 12+3=15; ergo, 13 returns 13+3=16.

Comment: thats the problem, see the index 16 example, since we have to skip 4 indexes, which land us on index 20, which is again a multiple of 4, so we skip that one and goes to next index 21. There should be an easy way than my recursion logic??

Comment: Ah! I see now. One moment, then, let me have another look at the code.

Answer (score 2):

Every block of four consecutive numbers—like 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5, 6, 7, 8—contains three usable indices and one that should be skipped. So all we need to do is:

- Divide by three to get the number of blocks needed.
- Multiply that number by four to switch from a number of usable indices to a number of original indices.
- Add the remainder modulo three to account for position within the last block.
- Adjust because we apparently want to start with index 1. Thus adjustment is to subtract one (to convert to zero-based indices), do the calculation described above, and then add one (to convert back to one-based indices).

This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int fn(int i)
{
    return (i-1)/3*4 + (i-1)%3 + 1;
}


int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 17; ++i)
        printf("%d -> %d.\n", i, fn(i));
}
```

produces this output:

```
1 -> 1.
2 -> 2.
3 -> 3.
4 -> 5.
5 -> 6.
6 -> 7.
7 -> 9.
8 -> 10.
9 -> 11.
10 -> 13.
11 -> 14.
12 -> 15.
13 -> 17.
14 -> 18.
15 -> 19.
16 -> 21.
```